# Were there two appearances of Stan Lee?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame, stan-lee

As has been the case since the first Marvel movie that's been released, Mr. Stan Lee has had a cameo in every single MCU movie (at least, that I'm aware of.)

This was true for this film, and shouldn't be considered a spoiler to anyone.  We obviously see him as both a minor character and he has a speaking role, and the scene is pretty obvious.  However...

> When we see Scott (Ant-Man) come out of the quantum vortex, we see him running around the city until he gets to the memorial garden with all of the local names of the people who've vanished, trying to find the name of his daughter. 
>  
> Looking through these names, I noticed that on the last tablet there were multiple names ending in "Lee", however, I couldn't scan all of the names fast enough to see if "Stan Lee" was one of them.  In my opinion, it would have been an excellent place to have given Mr. Excelsior one last cameo, considering he's passed away wand this is considered the end of a rather long story arc.

So, does Stan Lee appear in this portion of the movie as well?

Comment: Related: [Snap victim memorial reference in Avengers: Endgame](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/100206/63559) on Movies

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are only two "Lee"s visible on the wall; **Ian Lee** (glimpsed) and **Charlotte Lee** (below Scott Lang).

[image]

Comment: I think we have to assume that this memorial is only one of many. This must be the local San Francisco memorial. Otherwise there would have to be over a hundred million people just for the States. And there would be tens of thousands of Lees and Langs. (And if there were oly one, why would it necessarily be in SF?)    Why would Stan Lee necessarily be in San Francisco?

Comment: @ThePopMachine - Also, the alphabetisation on these memorials is shocking.

Answer (score 7):

To complement [Valorum’s answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/211047/58193) the Russo’s have spoken about Stan Lee’s cameo in *Avengers: Endgame* and only mention the part in person in 1970 and don't mention anything about the memorial.

This would indicate that Stan Lee *doesn’t* have his name listed as it isn't mentioned when an opportunity was given to talk about his final involvement in the film.

> “It’s sort of the hippie era, and Stan’s cameoing as a hippie and it’s the free-love era,” Joe Russo explains. “He’s saying, ‘Make love, not war!’”
>
> [...]
>
> “It’s the last Stan Lee cameo that made it to film,” Joe says.
>
> <sub>[Entertainment Weekly, Avengers: Endgame explained: Stan Lee's final cameo](https://ew.com/movies/2019/04/26/avengers-endgame-stan-lee-cameo/)</sub>

Comment: Easter egg references apparently count since Taika Waititi said that the sculpture of Stan (in Ragnarok) was a "cameo"

Comment: There's also his appearance in GotG 2 talking to the Watchers, which they come back to in a post-credits scene.

Comment: It would make sense that no honorary mention was made in Endgame, I have yet to see it, but Stan told Larry King he did not get paid for any of his cameo appearances. He was not very clear, but MCU and Marvel Comics are not really one and the same so all those cameos were kind of a nod at his contribution but no payment was made according to Stan. Keep in mind also his last name is not really "Lee", its Stanley Martin Lieber, but everyone would shout "yo Stanleee!" back in the day in NYC. I feel he should have gotten more props than just cameo, at one point he ran Marvel almost by himself.

Comment: I think we have to assume that this memorial is only one of many. This must be the local San Francisco memorial. Otherwise there would have to be over a hundred million people just for the States. And there would be tens of thousands of Lees and Langs. (And if there were oly one, why would it necessarily be in SF?)    Why would Stan Lee necessarily be in San Francisco?

Answer (score 1):

Mild Endgame spoilers:

> The pillars only contained names of people missing after the first Snap. Since Stan was not included, he either died (in-universe) outside of it, or is still alive during Endgame's present day.

Comment: Or just wasn't seen. We only glimpse a few dozen names out of millions

Comment: I think we have to assume that this memorial is only one of many.   This must be the local San Francisco memorial.   Otherwise there would have to be over a hundred million people just for the States.   And there would be tens of thousands of Lees and Langs.    (And if there were oly one, why would it necessarily be in SF?)

Comment: Well, there's a bit of the expectation that if it did happen, it would have been shown.